# What does send() do in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Can someone please tell me what the following snippet

```ruby
obj.send("#{method_name}")
```

is and does?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

`send` sends a message to an object instance and its ancestors in class hierarchy until some method reacts (because its name matches the first argument).

Practically speaking, those lines are equivalent:

```
1.send '+', 2
1.+(2)
1 + 2
```

Note that `send` bypasses visibility checks, so that you can call private methods, too (useful for unit testing).

---

If there is really no variable before send, that means that the global Object is used:

```
send :to_s    # "main"
send :class   # Object
```

Comment: Oh I see, so one might use send if one wanted to store something like 1.month on the database instead of statically saying the number of days.

Comment: True, you could use it to call method with names that are computed, not static. (You shouldn't allow unrestricted user input, though, to avoid calling private methods... You could, however, give them a unique prefix: send 'user_method_'+methodname, *args)

Comment: Good use case might be it you want to test a protected class method, you could call it outside a class—in test file..

Answer (score 136):

*send* is a Ruby method allowing to invoke another method by name passing it any arguments specified.

```ruby
 class Klass
   def hello(*args)
     "Hello " + args.join(' ')
   end
 end
 k = Klass.new
 k.send :hello, "gentle", "readers"   #=> "Hello gentle readers"
```

[Source](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Object.html#method-i-send)

Answer (score 81):

One of the most useful feature I think with .send method is that it can dynamically call on method. This can save you a lot of typing. One of the most popular use of .send method is to assign attributes dynamically. For example:

```
class Car
  attr_accessor :make, :model, :year
end
```

To assign attributes regularly one would need to

```
c = Car.new
c.make="Honda"
c.model="CRV"
c.year="2014"
```

Or using .send method:

```
c.send("make=", "Honda")
c.send("model=", "CRV")
c.send("year=","2014")
```

But it can all be replaced with the following:

Assuming your Rails app needs to assign attributes to your car class from user input, you can do

```
c = Car.new()
params.each do |key, value|
  c.send("#{key}=", value)
end
```

Comment: Using .send in this manner adds unnecessary complexity and makes it easier to inadvertently introduce a bug into the code.  For example, in your code above, if you add a new entry to your parameters hash (such as 'cylinders'), the code will fail with an undefined method error.

Comment: respond_to? could be used to prevent such errors, if desired.

Comment: @Kevin you are right, but sometimes it may be necessary. More flexibility correlates to more risk, which can be mitigated.

Comment: I always `rescue NoMethodError` when using `send` and either send the error to a log and/or implement some default behavior that should be done in the event of an undefined method.

Answer (score 18):

Another example, similar to Antonio Jha's https://stackoverflow.com/a/26193804/1897857

is if you need to read attributes on an object.

For example, if you have an array of strings, if you try to iterate through them and call them on your object, it won't work.

```
atts = ['name', 'description']
@project = Project.first
atts.each do |a|
  puts @project.a
end
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `a'
```

However, you can `send` the strings to the object:

```
atts = ['name', 'description']
@project = Project.first
atts.each do |a|
  puts @project.send(a)
end
# => Vandalay Project
# => A very important project
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly the answer I am after. Wondering is this commonly used? I came across something similar in the legacy code, not sure I should stick with it.@Mike Vallano

Comment: @b-liu I've seen it used by experienced developers in new code. It can also be helpful when using `define_method`: https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/define_method.

Answer (score 14):

#### What does send do?

`send` is another way of "calling a method". Example:

```
o = Object.new
o.to_s # => "#<Object:0x00005614d7a24fa3>"
# is equivalent to:
o.send(:to_s) # => "#<Object:0x00005614d7a24fa3>"
```

[Send lives in the Object class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Object.html#method-i-send).

#### What is the benefit of this?

The benefit of this approach is that you can pass in the method you want to call as a parameter. Here is a simple example:

```
def dynamically_call_a_method(method_name)
    o = Object.new
    o.send method_name
end
dynamically_call_a_method(:to_s) # => "#<Object:0x00005614d7a24fa3>"
```

You can pass in the method you want to be called. In this case we passed in `:to_s`. This can be very handy when doing ruby metaprogramming, because this allows us to call different methods according to our different requirements.

Answer (score 5):

Send can also be used as a way of showing how everything in Ruby is an object

```
1.send(:+, 1)  ## -> 2
3.send(:*, 2)  ## -> 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Another use case for views:

```
    <%= link_to 
    send("first_part_of_path_#{some_dynamic_parameters}_end_path", 
    attr1, attr2), ....
    %>
```

Allow . you to write scalable view who work with all kind of objects
with:

```
    render 'your_view_path', object: "my_object"
```

Comment: This adds unnecessary logic to views and could have security implications. Don't do this. Use arrays and hashes.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty late to the topic. As a noob I just used it and wanted to be helpful to people like me who wanted straightforward answer.
filter_hash.each{|k,v| order_additional_hash[send(method_name, k)] = v}

as seen above send(method_name) is the method, which we want to call. It matches the name and calls the method if the method name is passed as string in the params and k is the argument we want to pass in the method.