# send method in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I just read about what `send` does in Ruby and I'm still confused when looking at this code (it's from a quiz but its past due date anyways)

```
x = [1,2,3]
x.send :[]=,0,2
x[0] + x.[](1) + x.send(:[],2)
```

I understand that the first line assigns an array to x
then I don't understand what `:[] = ,0,2` does at all and i dont understand why send is needed there
I dont get what `x.[](1)` does and x.send(:[],2) do on the last line

I'm really confused and I just cant find this information online.

I found the what [send does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337285/what-does-send-do-in-ruby) but I'm still a little bit confused and a lot of bit confused about this code as a whole.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

First of all, things like `[]` (array index) and `[]=` are just methods in Ruby. `x` is an `Array`, and arrays have a `[]=` method, which accepts two arguments, an index and a value to set.

Using `send` lets you pass an arbitrary "message" (method call) to object, with arbitrary parameters.

You could call `x.send :sort`, for example, to send the "sort" message to the array. Sort doesn't need any parameters, though, so we don't have to pass anything extra to it.

`x#[]=`,  on the other hand, accepts two arguments. Its method can be thought of to look like this:

```
def []=(index, value)
  self.set_value_at_index(index, value)
end
```

So, we can just invoke it with `send :[]=, 0, 2`, which is just like calling `x[0] = 2`. Neat, huh?

Comment: alright I still dont understand the comma why isnt it :[]= 0,2 ??

Comment: @Xitcod13 Because :[]= is an argument of send, too: `send(:[]=, 0, 2)`

Answer (score 24):

In Ruby, `a[0] = 2` is actually syntactic sugar for `a.[]=(0, 2)`.

Knowing this, that's what your second line does—it calls the `[]=` method with two arguments using metaprogramming, as you correctly guessed.

This is the same for your third line: `a[0]` is syntactic sugar in Ruby for `x.[](0)`.

The following code is a simpler equivalent to your example:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
x[0] = 2
x[0] + x[1] + x[2]
```

Answer (score 22):

Don't worry. Ruby can be a little bit tricky in these cases. Let's examine the code line by line:

```
x = [1,2,3]
x.send :[]=,0,2
x[0] + x.[](1) + x.send(:[],2)
```

### First line

First line is clear to you: it assigns an array of three elements to x. And that's just about it.

### Second line

Second line calls the [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-send) method of `x` passing a symbol (remember that everything that starts with `:` is a symbol in ruby) `:[]=`, `0` (a `Fixnum`) and `2` (another `Fixnum`).
Now you just have to take a look at what the send method does (as you said you've already done):

> Invokes the method identified by symbol, passing it any arguments specified

This means that it will invoke the method identified by `:[]=` and pass `0` and `2` to it. Now let's take a look at the [`Array#[]=`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) method. This method definition (which can be *overloaded* by you if you need to do so) is:

```
class Array
    # ...
    def []=(a, b)
        # ...
    end
end
```

This method is called by `send` as `x.[]=(0, 2)` which is pretty ugly if you ask me. That's why Ruby defines a syntactic sugar version: `x[0] = 2` and in general:

```
x.[]=(a, b)  -->  x[a] = b
```

In the `Array` case we also have the following:

```
x.[](a)  -->  x[a]
```

In both cases you are free to call whatever version makes sense to you in the specific context.

### Third line

Now for the third and last line:

```
x[0] + x.[](1) + x.send(:[],2)
```

things gets really tricky. Let's divide it into:

1. `x[0]`
2. `x.[](1)`
3. `x.send(:[], 2)`

The first one is pretty straight forward. It returns the first element of the array.

The second one is the syntactic sugar that we have seen earlier which can be basically be *converted* into `x[1]` which returns the second element of the array.

The third one uses `Object#send` to call the method `[]` passing `2` to it. Which means that it calls `x.[](2)` which means `x[2]`.

### Conclusion

The code

```
x = [1,2,3]
x.send :[]=,0,2
x[0] + x.[](1) + x.send(:[],2)
```

can be converted using:

```
x.send(:[]=, a, b)  -->  x.[]=(a, b)
x.send(:[], a)  -->  x.[](a)
x.[]=(a, b)  -->  x[a] = b
x.[](a)  -->  x[a]
```

to:

```
x = [1,2,3]
x[0] = 2
x[0] + x[1] + x[2]
```

which can be reduced to:

```
2 + 2 + 3
```

which results in:

```
7
```

Comment: @Jeffery Nice explanation..Can u please explain how x[1]=2

Comment: @PeeVee, The element with index `1`, in the array `x`, is the second: `2`.

Answer (score 7):

`send` is a way to achieve reflection calls in ruby. Thus this line:

```
x.send :[]=,0,2
```

Is equivalent to:

```
x[0] = 2
```

you read it that way: the name of the method is symbol (in your case `[]=`) and then you pass in the parameters - 0 and 2.

Answer (score 2):

x[0]+x[1]+x[2]=2+2+3=7
i guess this must be the answer