# Ruby function as value of hash

Tags: ruby, function

I was wondering if or how it is possible to map a function to a value of a hash.

For example:
----Start Class------------

```
def foo(var)
    return var + 2
end

hash_var = { func => foo() }
```

----End Class--------------

so that I could later call

```
Class::hash_var["func"][10]
```

or

```
Class::hash_var["func"](10)
```

and that would return 12?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions/methods are one of the few things in Ruby that are not objects, so you can't use them as keys or values in hashes. The closest thing to a function that is an object would be a proc. So you are best off using these...

The other answers pretty much listed all possible ways of how to put a proc into a hash as value, but I'll summarize it nonetheless ;)

```
hash = {}

hash['variant1'] = Proc.new {|var| var + 2}
hash['variant2'] = proc     {|var| var + 2}
hash['variant3'] = lambda   {|var| var + 2}

def func(var)
  var + 2
end

hash['variant4'] = method(:func) # the *method* method returns a proc
                                 # describing the method's body
```

there are also different ways to evaluate procs:

```
hash['variant1'].call(2) # => 4
hash['variant1'][2]      # => 4
hash['variant1'].(2)     # => 4
```

Answer (score 10):

You could use [`method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-method) method.

```
def foo(var)
      return var + 2
end

hash_var = { :func => method(:foo) }

hash_var[:func].call(10)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the value to a Proc and call it.

```
hash_var = {
  'func' =>  proc {|x| x+2}
}

hash_var['func'].call(10) #=> 12
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using lambdas

```
hash_var = { :func => lambda { |var| var + 2 }}
hash_var['func'].call(5) #=> 7
```

Comment: The lambda method has the same effect as the proc method; they both yield Proc objects containing the provided block.

Comment: Yup , i know !! I did not see the proc answer before i posted my answer !!

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be:

```
def foo(name)
    puts "Hi #{name}"
end

def bar(numb)
    puts numb + 1
end

hash_var = { func: :foo, func2: :bar }
send hash_var[:func], "Grid"
# => Hi Grid
send hash_bar[:func2], 3
# => 4
```

Here is some information about the [#send](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Object.html#method-i-send) method [What does send() do in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337285/what-does-send-do-in-ruby)