# Rails jQuery POST - ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using rails 4.1.

I have setup a custom controller. I have configured the routes with:

```
resources :chats
```

I am trying to make a post request to the controller using jQuery. Here is the code:

```
$.post('/chats/', { session: { advisor_id: $(this).attr('data-id') } }, function (data) {
    eval(data);
});
```

Edit: And here is the code for my controller -

```
class ChatsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    #create the new session
    @session = Session.create(:advisor_id => session_params[:advisor_id], :session_type => @session.call!, :client_id => current_user.id)

  end

  private
    def session_params
     params[:session].permit(:advisor_id, :client_id, :session_type)
    end
end
```

Edit: And here is the code for my model -

```
class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum session_type: [ :chat, :call ]
  belongs_to :client, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => :client_id
  belongs_to :advisor, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => :advisor_id
  has_many :instant_messages

  def self.obj_name(id)
    o = Session.find(id)
    "#{o.client.full_name} and #{o.advisor.full_name}"
  end
end
```

However it throws an error which is:

> ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (1 for 0):
>     activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
>     actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in`process_action'
>     actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
>     actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in`block in process_action'
>     activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
>     activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in`instrument'
>     activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
>     actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in`process_action'
>     actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
>     activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in`process_action'
>     actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
>     actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in`process'
>     actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
>     actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in`dispatch'
>     actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
>     actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in`dispatch'
>     actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
>     actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in`block in call'
>     actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
>     actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in`call'
>     rack-pjax (0.7.0) lib/rack/pjax.rb:12:in `call'
>     warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in`block in call'
>     warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
>     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in`call'
>     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
>     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in`call'
>     remotipart (1.2.1) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:27:in `call'
>     actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in`call'
>     actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
>     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in`context'
>     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
>     actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in`call'
>     activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
>     activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in`call'
>     activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
>     actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in`block in call'
>     activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
>     actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in`call'
>     actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
>     actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in`call'
>     better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
>     better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in`better_errors_call'
>     better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
>     actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in`call'
>     actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
>     railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in`call_app'
>     railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
>     activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in`block in tagged'
>     activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
>     activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in`tagged'
>     railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
>     quiet_assets (1.0.2) lib/quiet_assets.rb:18:in`call_with_quiet_assets'
>     actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
>     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in`call'
>     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
>     activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in`call'
>     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
>     actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in`call'
>     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
>     railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in`call'
>     railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
>     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in`call'
>     thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
>     thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in`pre_process'
>     thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
>     thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in`receive_data'
>     eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
>     thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in`start'
>     thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
>     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in`run'
>     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
>     railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in`start'
>     railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
>     railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in`server'
>     railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
>     railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in`'
>     bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
>     ruby-debug-ide (0.4.23.beta1) lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:86:in`debug_program'
>     ruby-debug-ide (0.4.23.beta1) bin/rdebug-ide:110:in `<top (required)>'
>     -e:1:in`'

Why is it throwing this error? How can I get it to accept the request?

Comment: Can we actually see your Controller method for the POST action?

Comment: The error will be to do with your controller backend (which you've not posted). The actual error is `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` - are you calling any `ActiveRecord` methods with an argument?

Comment: I have added the code for the controller.

Comment: We need to see your models, looks like you have a create method redefined without argumentos or you are doing a before, after callback.

Comment: Even when I comment out the create code and the other code it still does it...

Comment: Could you try to start server via " rails s " command and redo tp give me error log again

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem. The issue was that I had an action in the controller called "send". I now know that "send" is a method used in ruby to call other methods.

Here is some more info on the ruby "send" method. [What does send() do in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337285/what-does-send-do-in-ruby)

Comment: Thank you! Have been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out what was causing this.

Comment: Be aware that you can hit this snag with a controller action matching *any* pre-existing method. I just experienced the same problem, but it was due to my use of `process` which is a Rails-defined method on `ActionController::Base`.