# Understanding methods and syntax used in a Ruby code

Tags: ruby

I would like to understand a code that creates a RPN calculator:

```
class RPNCalculator
  def evaluate(expression)
    operators = ["+", "-", "*"]
    stack = []
    array = expression.split(" ")
    array.each do |i|
      if operators.include?(i)
        second_operand = stack.pop
        first_operand = stack.pop
        stack.push(first_operand.send(i, second_operand))
      else
        stack.push(i.to_i)
      end
    end
    stack.pop
  end
end
```

I do not understand these lines in particular:

```
if operators.include?(i)
  second_operand = stack.pop
  first_operand = stack.pop
  stack.push(first_operand.send(i, second_operand))
else
  stack.push(i.to_i)
```

If someone could give me a full run down of the code, it would be very helpful.

Comment: play computer: for the characters in the string, write down all the steps. or if you don't have a pencil, put in a lot of print statements.

Comment: @Dave, another option would be to buy a pencil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stack` is a place to keep the intermediate state of the calculation. Initially, it is an empty array. During the calculation, it should be filled with integers, and at the end, it should be filled with a single integer, which is the result of the calculation.

`if operators.include?(i)` checks if the next element `i` is within the list of operators `["+", "-", "*"]`. If it is, then

```
second_operand = stack.pop
first_operand = stack.pop
```

removes the last two elements in the `stack`, and

```
first_operand.send(i, second_operand)
```

calculates the value with `i` being the operator and the two elements being the operands. Then

```
stack.push(...)
```

puts back the calculated value. Otherwise,

```
stack.push(i.to_i)
```

converts the element (string) into an integer, and appends to the stack.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not great in Ruby myself but some of this applies to other languages as well so I'll give it a shot.

So by the time you get to the block you mentioned, `array` contains the equation and `stack` is empty. Let's say the expression is `2 5 * 1 +`, so `array` is equal to `["2", "5", "*", "1", "+"]`.

The `.each` block will iterate through `array`. First we check to see if the item is an operator (in the `operators` array). Initially, it isn't (it's `2`) so we just convert it to a number and push that to the stack. So now `stack` is `[2]`. Same thing with the next iteration, it isn't an operator, so now `stack` is `[2, 5]`.

The next item in the array is "*", which does exist in the `operators` array. So let's set to vars: we pop the first item off of `stack` and set `second_operand` (that is the 5) and pop another into `first_operand` (the 2) and calculate the result. That's where [send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337285/what-does-send-do-in-ruby) comes in. That result, 10, now goes into `stack` (which now is `[10]`.

Another number, so `stack` is now `[10, 1]`. Then the "+". So once again, pop the 10, pop the 1, and do the addition, and push back into `stack`: `[11]`.

We're all done, so pop the 11 out of `stack` and return that value.