# Is there a send method in JavaScript the way there is in Ruby to help DRY this up?

Tags: jquery, ruby, jquery-steps

I am using the [jquery-steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/) plugin and would like to call the `steps` initialization method on another form but with the same settings.

Is there a way to tell JavaScript to do this without having to call `steps` again with the same settings?  I'm thinking of something analogous to the `send` method in Ruby if that helps.

Source code:

```
var formWizard = $('form#myform').children('div.page-1');
formWizard.steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
       bodyTag: "section"
    //other settings that make this steps method long
});
```

I want to use a `send` method like Ruby or some other way to avoid repeating the steps call with all the arguments:

```
var formWizard2 = $('form#myform').children('div.page-2');
var hash_args = {
    headerTag: "h3",
       bodyTag: "section"
    //other settings that make this steps method long
}
formWizard2.send(:steps, hash_args)
```

Comment: You don't use `send` in Ruby to pass arguments to a method or set up default arguments, you use `send` to call a method whose name isn't known until runtime. Your question doesn't make any sense as it is.

Comment: mu, you can use send to invoke another method by name: "send is a ruby (without rails) method allowing to invoke another method by name." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337285/what-does-send-do-in-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding your question... but why don't you just save the config to a variable and use it:

```
var config = {
        headerTag: "h3",
        bodyTag: "section"
        //other settings that make this steps method long
}

formWizard.steps(config);
var formWizard2 = $('form#myform').children('div.page-2');
formWizard2.send(config)
```