# ruby self.send how to understand

Tags: ruby

```
  class LogEntry
    attr_reader :term, :index, :command

    def initialize(term, index, command)
      @term, @index, @command = term, index, command
    end

    def ==(other)
      [:term, :index, :command].all? do |attr|
        self.send(attr) == other.send(attr)
      end
    end

    def eql?(other)
      self == other
    end

    def hash
      [:term, :index, :command].reduce(0) do |h, attr|
        h ^= self.send(attr)
      end
    end
  end
```

I am reading a code like this, how to understand `"self.send"` at this line?

```
self.send(attr) == other.send(attr)
```

thanks

Comment: Did you read ruby-doc?(http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-send)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3337285/2988

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a fancy way of doing:

```
self.term == other.term and
self.index == other.index and
self.comment == other.comment
```