# Rails - Can't get nested attribute without dot notation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm facing an issue with ruby because I'm trying to get a nested attribute like that:

```
row :ratings do |ratings|
        table_for ratings.list do
          column :promptness do |list|
            table_for rating.list.promptness do
              column :rating
              column :comment
            end
          end
        end
end
```

I can get the data with the dot notation but I can't make it work using the [] notation like this:

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].each do |el|
          table_for ratings.list do
            column el do |list|
              table_for rating.list[el] do
                column :rating
                column :comment
              end
            end
          end
      end
```

What's the reason in this? How could I eventually solve this?
Thank you for any help

Comment: In Javascript the dot and hash notation are the same. But not in Ruby. Only for certain cases (open struct for example) are they interchangable.

Comment: @maxple Alright, thanks for your answer. What would be the best solution in my case then? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here:

```
table_for rating.list[el] do
```

won't work, like you know, because `list` doesn't respond to `[]`.

Instead, you can do this, since `el` is a symbol:

```
table_for rating.list.send(el) do
```

See [What does send() do in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337285/what-does-send-do-in-ruby)